# dynamic drop down list custom field wordpress

Tags: wordpress, dynamic-list

I am working on a WordPress blog but have little development knowledge.

I want to add a custom field in the form of a dynamic drop down list where users can choose county/city/district, so second list is dependent on the first and the third on the second. i can't seem to find a plugin that does this and can't figure out how to do this on my own.

I am using advanced custom fields plugin to add custom fields.

Thanks!

Comment: You want these fields in wp-admin?

Comment: yes :) this is a blog working on wordpress and i need to make this in wordpress

Comment: if you make custom then its will be better. @riham nour

Comment: well, I don't know how to do it and that's why I'm asking for help. ACF plugin doesn't have the feature of dynamic drop down lists.

Comment: You want this for a custom post type?

Comment: I want to add a custom field to be a dynamic drop down list in the form of country/city/district so users can choose the location as a custom field